# Replace quotes with &quot; and substr function for words

Tags: php, str-replace, quotes

I am trying to replace double quotations with the word " before inserting into the database, but when trying to fetch my text from the database I cannot convert the quotes after using this function to display certain words from the whole sentence.

What I eventually want to do:

1. Input the string `Word "blabla" more text` for example to the database
2. Before putting to the database, convert the special characters like `"` to the correct code (`&quote;`)
3. When retrieving the string from the database, it must put the code `&quote;` again to `"` to display on my page

Besides that, I also want to create a function that works like `substr()` but splits on full words instead of single characters.

This is my current code:

```
function sanitize_words($string) {
    preg_match_all("/\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}'\x{2019}]*/u",$string,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    return $matches[0];
}
function words($text,$len) {
    $words_in_text = sanitize_words($text);
    $words_to_return = $len;
    $result = array_slice($words_in_text,0,$words_to_return);
    return implode(" ",$result);
}
```

However when I try to replace the `"quot;"` text back to normal `"` quotes, it doesn't show on my page.

Comment: Perhaps the problem to solve here is to find out what happened to those ampersands.

Comment: why aren't you replacing the entire `&quot;`?

Comment: Yes, Jack is right. You have some code that strips out the & and ; - find that...

Comment: have you tried `htmlspecialchars_decode($string);`. But if you are viewing in html you don't need to do anything. Browsers will show `"` instead of `&quot`

Comment: @sevenseacat He shouldn't have to replace them at all. The shown entities are better than `"`

Comment: question updated please review

Comment: @jqbeginner Could you try simply not using the `sanitize_words` function, and instead using `htmlentities()` and `html_entity_decode()` ? Note: Take a look at the documentation too, you may need to give some parameters along with it to get the encoding right: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: i use this function to substr some words not characters and it works well without using the above function

Comment: @jqbeginner Your `sanitize_words` function *does* seem to give you problems with the entities (your quotes). Either the function is wrong or you are trying to do the wrong thing.

Comment: @DarkAshelin It *seems* to be correct in the database though.

Comment: it does return the words with the same count I decide it works well but doesn't return the quotations after the replace

Comment: Are you using the `sanitize_words` function before you insert in the database, or after you retrieve it from the database?

Comment: it's in the database like this &quot; text &quot;

Comment: Check my question: are you using the `sanitize_words` function *before* or *after* you get the text from the database?

Comment: after $intro = str_replace("quot",'"',$blockRow03['News_Intro']); 
  echo words($intro,40);

Comment: It seems we're running in circles, let's continue in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50320/room-for-dark-ashelin-and-jq-beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After our discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50320/room-for-dark-ashelin-and-jq-beginner), we managed to solve it as following:

### Problem 1

Inserting html entities in the database and correctly displaying it again in html.

1. Before inputting the string to the database, use this function to convert the special characters to the correct entity codes:

   `$newstring = htmlentities( $oldstring , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`
2. Then input `$newstring` into your database. It will have special characters like `"` converted to `&quote;`.
3. When retrieving the string from the database, it should automatically show the correct symbol (`"`) in the html, without you having to do anything!

If you are still having trouble with displaying the string, then you can check [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

### Problem 2

Creating a function that works like `substr()`, but works with words instead of single characters.

```
function subword($string, $amount){
    $explode = explode(" ", $string);
    $newstring = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++){
        $newstring.= " ".$explode[$i];
    }
    return substr($newstring, 1);
};

$text = "This is a sentence with a lot of words and spaces!";
subword($text, 4);  //This will give you the first 4 words "This is a sentence"
```